# Can not insert a hexed string into int array

Tags: java, hex

```
int[] myArray= new int[16];
myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt("0x6a");
```

I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Duncin.Main.main(Main.java:72)`

Although I have seen it work places such as this one.

```
private final int[] myArray = new int[]{ 0x57, 0x49, 0xd1, 0xc6, 0x2f };
```

Comment: Would you like to parse an array of 2-char hex strings, or a single string of concatenated 2-char hex values, into an array of int? And if so are you using java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse as base 16 :

```
myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt("6a", 16);
```

The single argument `parseInt` tries to parse a decimal number.

In addition, remove the "0x".

Comment: still the same exception

Comment: You have to get rid of `0x` as well. Just put `"6a"` as String

Comment: @tony9099 Yep, forgot to remove the 0x. Thanks for the comment Loki

Comment: This is it. I will accept the answer int the next 10 minutes